# Tomcat process blocks other process from rebinding to porton restart

Tags: java, servlets, network-programming

This is a bit complicated, and possible belongs on some other StackExchange site.

We have a Tomcat web app and an "audit" application.  The audit application runs in its own process, and listens to port 60000 for HTTP requests.  Under normal conditions, Tomcat sends audit data via HTTP to the audit process.  Both processes run on the same host.

The system is CentOS 5.7, Tomcat is version 6.0.33. The audit application is a Flume Agent.

Occasionally, our audit application needs to be restarted.  When it does, it usually succeeds.

But a little too often for our comfort, when the audit application restarts, it fails with a BindException on port 60000.  We can stop the audit application, make sure it is really dead, and start it again, but it fails consistently.  The only way to resolve the problem is to restart the Tomcat server - somehow, it is blocking the audit application from listening on port 60000.

When we do an "lsof" while audit app is down, and look for data on port 60000, we get:

```
java      13178    tomcat   47u     IPv6     34165085         TCP <hostname>:60000-><hostname>:60000 (ESTABLISHED)
```

We can't really understand how this Tomcat process, which only writes to localhost:60000, is occasionally blocking other applications from listening to port 60000.

The web app is using the default HTTP connection caching that is built into Java, if that might be related.

Comment: It could be related to fin_wait_2 not timing out. Try setting this to a small value. What does netstat -an show?

Comment: @jontro Whoops, no, I need to wait until it gets into that state again.  Ignore last comment (deleted.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews how the app on Tomcat sends the data? It opens a socket to port 60000 ?

Comment: It opens an HttpURLConnection. The Java runtime is free to re-use connections and apply connection pooling that way, but it means the specifics of the code are a bit lost to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing it has to do with port 60000 being in the "ephemeral port"[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port) range. Perhaps your Tomcat Webapp is somehow sometimes grabbing port 60000 in a way that prevents another app from binding to the port.  Maybe try using a port that isn't in the ephemeral range for your audit server?

Comment: Yeah, I thought of this possibility, but haven't given it a try because I couldn't see a mechanism whereby this was happening.  It's now higher on my list of things to try.

Comment: Yep, was able to reproduce this problem listening in port 60000, but not on ports outside the ephemeral range.